# Blogs view for users

Tags: views

I have a drupal page with the blog module. Every user has his own Blog, reachable by site.name/en/blogs/user.name but on the blog entry i have added an new field where i can list all Authors. I need now a view which reads this information out of this and show all blog entries of this Author in his blog. Because now, there is the entry only on the blog of his owner. thanks (drupal 7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution. Install the Module Entity Reference, then create an multiple field wich is linked to the user Profile, at least you have to add a view to `blogs/%` and there you have to add an context filter wich filters to the field which refers to the Username.